# How do i fix dependency issue with apport and apt-get (ubuntu 16.04 upgraded from 14.04)

Tags: apt, dependencies, python3, apport

I'm having trouble with dependencies and apt-get upgrade.  I've looked around and tried a group of approches from this site and other stuff found on google.

```
b@asus:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apport : Depends: python3-apport (>= 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1) but 2.20.1-0ubuntu2 is installed
 apport-gtk : Depends: python3-apport (>= 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1) but 2.20.1-0ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I've tried using sudo apt-get -f install and other things like autoremove and autoclean, but I'm having no luck.

This also came up when I apt-get upgrade:

```
Get:124 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 compizconfig-settings-manager all 1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160526-0ubuntu1 [576 kB]
Fetched 160 MB in 2min 47s (955 kB/s)                                          
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 252887 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-problem-report_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1_all.deb ...
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 106

          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 106

          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1_all.deb ...
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 106

          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 106

          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../init-system-helpers_1.29ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking init-system-helpers (1.29ubuntu2) over (1.29ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you done sudo apt-get install --fix-missing?

Comment: i get a pretty much the same error:

    b@asus:~$ sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
    [sudo] password for b: 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
        The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.1.2-0ubuntu1) but 1:5.1.3-0ubuntu1 is installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: this may get annoying but have you tried to custom install all of the dependencies(just a thought).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the same problem just by using python 2.7 instead of python 3.4:

```
 sudo rm python
 sudo ln -s python2.7 python
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo rm python
 sudo ln -s python3.4 python
```